# Enable in-app product purchase (remove banner)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I'm developing an uwp app, which has advertising and was creating a button to remove the advertising and is giving me this error: "System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code"
The error happens here: 
`if (!AppLicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["removeAd"].IsActive)`
This excerpt of code is executed when I click the button to remove the ads

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: I do not understand why this errorhappens. And I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug it and see which element is null. You have cascading calls to AppLicenseInformation and ProductLicenses and the removeAd element. Any one of those could be null.

But in general, to use product licenses, you need to set up the consumable item you're selling ("removeAds") in the DevCenter for this app. And, when you're testing/debugging licenses, you also need to use CurrentAppSimulator to get license checks to work.

Check out information about CurrentAppSimulator on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.

Comment: I am using CurrentAppSimulator. And I have not yet submitted any submissions to the dev center

Comment: Test if either AppLicenseInformation or ProductLicenses are null when you debug your app.